# gojs: howto increase distance between links or links labels?

Tags: javascript, gojs

How to increase distance between links (double links)?

```
myDiagram.linkTemplate=
    $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
        $(go.Shape,  // the link shape
            { isPanelMain: true,
                stroke: "black" }),
        $(go.Shape,  // the arrowhead
            { toArrow: "standard",
                stroke: null }),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape,  // the link shape
                { fill: radgrad, stroke: null }),
            $(go.TextBlock,  // the label
                { textAlign: "center",
                    font: "10pt helvetica, arial, sans-serif",
                    stroke: "#919191",
                    margin: 4 },
                new go.Binding("text", "text"))
         )
     );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/66ENu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle the values of `link.curviness`:

```
myDiagram.linkTemplate=
    $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
      { curviness: 20 },
      // ... rest of link template
```

See [Link.curviness in the API](http://www.gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Link.html#curviness)