# Increase distance between links that both go from nodeA to nodeB

Tags: javascript, gojs

My question is quite similar to this post [gojs: howto increase distance between links or links labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676887/gojs-howto-increase-distance-between-links-or-links-labels), which was about increasing distance between two links with opposite direction by setting "curviness"(one link from A to B and the other from B to A).

But "curviness" doesn't work when two links have the same direction(both from A to B). Whatever value I set to curviness, the two links will totally overlap. So is there a way to increase the distance between links with the same direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `curviness` value is `NaN`, which means each link gets its own dynamic curviness value, and that value needs to be different for each link for multiple links to be seen.

So you can't do this just by changing the curviness. Instead you would need to override Link's `computeCurviness` to specify a different `Link.curviness` value for each link.

The [Dynamic ports sample](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/dynamicPorts.html) does this.

In the future GoJS may add a link Spacing property to allow easier spacing operations on links, but right now overriding is your best bet.